# dmar: Failed to find handle for ACPI object

Tags: debian, boot, linux-kernel, drivers, acpi

I'm using a Lenovo B50-50 with this specs:

- Intel Core i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4
- Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
- hard disk 500 GB
- Ram 4 GB

I'm currently running Debian(Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux)

The problem is that when I boot up the system (I am currently booting in "quiet splash" mode) the following messages are displayed:

```
[ 0.835186] dmar: Failed to find handle for ACPI object _SB.PCI0.SDMA
[ 0.835243] dmar: Failed to find handle for ACPI object _SB.PCI0.SDHC
```

Everything works fine after the boot.

What can, or should, I do about these messages?